# Python : Search on a Key and replace the next word before "," with a constant value in a very large windows file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have started learning Python pretty recently and came up with a requirement for which I need your help.
I have a mainframe background and this is pretty simple requirement which can be done using DFSORT but in python i have searched forum and google
but couldn't find any clue for this problem.

I have a large windows file which can be of 3GB to 5GB or even more.
My requirement is to search this file with a key in each line and if the key is found replace the next word before (ending) "," with XXXXXXXXXX 
the key is always "name:" and the value to be replaced is always before (,) following key. 
It might be possible that not all lines would have the key. If the value to be replaced is NULL then that value had to be ignored from replace

### Sample Input File :-

```
this is the name: roger,who won australian open
yes name: rafael nadal,who won french open
name: novak, is injured for this season
propably greatest of all time name: roger, had won wimbledon again.
this is the name: NULL,who will win US open !!!
```

### Output file

```
this is the name: XXXXXXXXXX,who won australian open
yes name: XXXXXXXXXX,who won french open
name: XXXXXXXXXX, is injured for this season
propably greatest of all time name: XXXXXXXXXX, had won wimbledon again.
this is the name: NULL,who will win US open !!!
```

Comment: also what if i want to replace multiple strings with multiple keys apart from above e.g. lets say i have one more key in each line like -  rank:123.21.222, which i want to replace with rank:999.999.999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addition to aoiee´s answer you can read text and rewrite it,

it might take longer if there is a lot data

```
import fileinput
import re
with open('path to file.txt or whatever', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
new_data = re.sub('name:([^,]+),', 'name: XXXXXXXXXX,', filedata)
with open('path to file.txt or whatever', 'w') as file:
  file.write(new_data)
```

Comment: Thank you i had tried this option(same as above code )  for a file of 20MB and it took 11 seconds. with a total number of records as 155202 and string repalced is - 15096.Before i run it on a huge file do you think this is good performance as i dont want to use CPU while others are using

Comment: @mikey that should be fine, you can try with 20 mb again and check your cpu during that 11 second, it should be fine

Comment: Thank you. 
also what if i want to replace multiple strings with multiple keys apart from above e.g. lets say i have one more key in each line like - rank:123.21.222, which i want to replace with rank:999.999.999

Comment: it is the same logic if the numbers are also finishing with "," just put it under first replacement :new_data = re.sub('rank:([^,]+),', 'rank: 999.999.999,', new_data)

Comment: Thank you just curious to know below cases 
1. what if i need to find a key and replace string before newline. 2. find  a key and replace constant value e.g. Address:12345679Abcdrefgh street here in this i need to fin Address: then replace neXt 9 digits with 9's i.e Address:99999999Abcdrefgh street

Comment: logic is same, you have to workaround the code to fit what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to capture the `name: anysequenceofcharacters,` string and replace it with `name: XXXXXXXXXX,`:

```
import re
with open('in', "rt") as fin:
with open('out', "wt") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(re.sub('name:(?! NULL)([^,]+),', 'name: XXXXXXXXXX,', line))
```

Comment: Thank you but how do i traverse all lines in this huge file and i'm afraid of the performance. can you please help me how to write an efficient code which can handle a huge file using regex

Comment: Also is it more efficient it write he updates to a new file instead of replacing in same file ?

Comment: You can read input file line by line, and output line by line to a new file.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, so here's an answer building off of @aoiee's that will traverse the file:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = file.read()
    text = re.sub('name:(?! NULL)([^,]+),', 'name: XXXXXXXXXX,', lines)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(text)
```

Comment: Thank you i had tried this option for a file of 20MB and it took 11 seconds. with a total number of records as 155202 and string repalced is - 15096.

Comment: Before i run it on a huge file do you think this is good performance as i dont want to use CPU while others are using.

Comment: it should be fine, but what computer are you using that others are using it as well?

Answer (score 0):

In case the each row is on a new line, you can do the following without a for loop:

```
def repel(mo):
    if mo.group(3) == 'NULL':
        return '{}{}{}{}'.format(mo.group(1), mo.group(2), mo.group(3), mo.group(4))
    return '{}{}{}{}'.format(mo.group(1), mo.group(2), 'XXXX,', mo.group(4))

pattern = re.compile('(.*)(name: )(\w+,)?(.*)')
re.sub(pattern, repel, _in, re.DOTALL)
```

This basically call repel function on every match, which replaces the part after `name:` with `XXXX`.

Comment: HI vinny i understood the repel part but can u let me know this statement -re.compile('(.*)(name: )(\w+,)?(.*)') also what does re.DOTALL do ?

Comment: re.compile compiles your pattern. Then instead of using a string pattern, you're using a compiled object. Each `( .. )` marks a group. I refer to these groups inside the repel function `mo.group(NUM)`. The DOTALL flag makes the `.` pattern match all chars including new lines. Without that the `.` matches everything except new line.. so it basically matches the pattern to multilines.